# SpringBoot do not allow empty lists in request body

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've have a simple SpringBoot app having a post route that takes a request body. I'm trying to force that body to have "route" property and it is need to be a list. But it cannot be an empty list.

This is my controller method:

```
@PostMapping("example")
public ResponseEntity<BodyDto> example(@Valid @RequestBody BodyDto bodyDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<BodyDto>(bodyDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and this is BodyDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BodyDto {

    @NonNull
    private List<String> route;
}
```

and when I send this, I want it to be failed because the "route" property is an empty list.

```
{
    "route": []
}
```

I've tried adding @NotEmpty, @Valid, @Size of javax.validation library to above of route property but it didn't worked. Is there any annotation for that purpose. If not, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: "@NotEmpty" instead of "@Nonnull"

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. But when I changed it to @NotEmpty, it still accepts the empty list and also null.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall I believe it should be flipped like so:

```
    @PostMapping("example")
public ResponseEntity<BodyDto> example(@RequestBody @NotEmpty BodyDto bodyDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<BodyDto>(bodyDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Also here is a guide: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank

Comment: I do not think that just adding that annotation is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the route list is empty and return error.  See code below.

```
@PostMapping("example")
public ResponseEntity<?> example(@RequestBody @NotEmpty BodyDto bodyDto) {
    if (bodyDto.getRoute() == null || bodyDto.getRoute().isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Route list is empty.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<BodyDto>(bodyDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

EDIT:  Based on the fact that you have multiple objects like this, then what you can do is look into utlizing `spring-boot-starter-validation`.  Here is a link that explains it.  https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can do that but I'm planning to have nested dtos which will have also lists that should not be empty. So I'll have to do that check for everything.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

I've added this to my pom.xml but it didn't work. Actually nothing about the validations seems to work. I've tried to use "Min", "Size" etc. nothing... Is there any configuration I need to add?

Comment: I've succeeded to validate "route". I was using the wrong validation library. I've changed it into jakarto from javax. However I've changed list type to another class from string. But it does not validate the inner json